# How to give pdf, certificate symbols in hyperlink

Tags: symbols

I am finding some pdf symbols to give as hyperref in a document as follows

[image]

What package would be good for this purpose?

Comment: some graphic file for the icon, `graphicx` and `hyperref`. You can give arbitrary contents in the `<text>` of `\href{<url>}{<text>}`, that includes images.

Comment: You can get the icon from the `fontawesome5` package